# R: Randomly switch signs of the off-diagonals in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, data-manipulation

Assume I generate the following matrix

```
Sigma <- diag(x = 1, 100, 100)
Sigma[Sigma == 0] <- 0.25
```

so having "1" on the diagonals and "0.25" on the off-diagonals. How can I randomly change some of the signs on the off diagonals to have -0.25 and 0.25 ?

Of course, one can loop over the elements but I think that is not an elegant solution there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to generate 1 and -1 randomly for length of the matrix, multiply it by the matrix and turn the diagonal to 1.

```
Sigma <- Sigma * sample(c(1, -1), length(Sigma), replace = TRUE)
diag(Sigma) <- 1
Sigma
```